# Error starting Apache Solr 4.x on TomCat 6.x: java.net.UnknownHostException: hostname: hostname: Name or service not known

Tags: linux, tomcat, solr

I would appreciate if someone could help resolve this issue logged in catalina.out, when starting tomcat6 service configured for Apache Solr 4.x on Linux:

```
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:29 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:29 PM org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector pause
SEVERE: Protocol handler pause failed
java.net.UnknownHostException: hostname: hostname: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.unLockSocket(ChannelSocket.java:485)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.pause(ChannelSocket.java:284)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkMain.pause(JkMain.java:725)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.pause(JkCoyoteHandler.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.pause(Connector.java:1022)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:618)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hostname: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
    ... 15 more

Mar 22, 2014 4:25:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:30 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 309 ms
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor solr.xml
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
WARNING: A docBase /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/solr] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/11  config=null
Mar 22, 2014 4:25:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 340 ms
```

I'm running this configuration locally on the server (localhost).

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have something like this in solr.xml

**File: solr.xml**

```
<solr persistent="false">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:8983}" hostContext="${hostContext:solr}">
    <core name="someCoreName" instanceDir="someCoreDirectory" properties="conf/solrcore.properties"/>
    <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory" class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
      <str name="urlScheme">${urlScheme:}</str>
    </shardHandlerFactory>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

**File: /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```